# Angular routing, refreshing gives 404, .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, angularjs

This has been asked multiple times, but still i don't seem to figure out whats the problem in my angular app.

My routing works fine, until I refresh the page and it gives me "page not found". Popular solution is that I add a .htaccess file to the root of my app, but it's still not working. I've even tried differrent .htaccess scripts.

Comment: Can you share what your main application.js looks like and your .htaccess file?

Comment: main.js where the configuration is: 
http://pastebin.com/59KTTQ54

.htaccess:
http://pastebin.com/cmb12RJ0

Comment: Have you set AllowOverride to All ?

Comment: are you sure mod_rewrite is really active?

Comment: One of the .htaccess files had "allowoverride all", but it wasn't helping (atleast in that script). Mod rewrite is loaded in the phpinfo apache "loaded modules".

Comment: I have this exact problem and nothing works!

Answer (score 11):

Try this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Did you test your answer ? I got this : "The requested URL /index.html/ was not found on this server."

Comment: @RomainFournereau That snippet is from one of my AngularJS projects. So yes, it works for me although YMMV depending on your environment/configuration.