# Angular Routing, HTML5 Mode and Apache

Tags: html, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, routes

I'm not having any luck getting this to work. I've tried several configurations, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069281/angular-routing-refreshing-gives-404-htaccess-not-working), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes) and [here](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/), but no matter what I do, page refreshes all end up with a 404. If I put `<my_base>/#/myPage` into my browser's URL bar, the page loads as expected, and the '/#' disappears. Then, if I try to reload, I get a 404. My setup is a single-page Angular web app: index.html has a single element that is the app's directive; this template has a navbar and an ng-view element that routes to the various pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to sysadmin, Apache's AllowOverride value is set to "None", which means that .htaccess files "won't work."